# SpringBoot Controller Layer Test throws JSONException : Unparsable JSON String

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I have some error with my controller layer test with springboot and JUnit5, Mockito.

```
@WebMvcTest(UsersController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class UsersControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private UsersController usersController;

    @MockBean
    private UsersService usersService;

    @MockBean
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @MockBean
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(usersController)
                .setControllerAdvice(UsersExceptionHandler.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("[Controller] Register")
    void Controller_Register_Test() throws Exception {
        //given
        Users users = Users.builder()
                .usersId("test@gmail.com")
                .nickname("testNickname")
                .password("testPassword")
                .build();

        UsersResponseDto responseDto = UsersResponseDto.builder()
                .users(users)
                .build();

        UsersSaveRequestDto requestDto = new UsersSaveRequestDto(
                "test@gmail.com",
                "testNickname",
                "testPassword"
        );

        //mocking
        when(usersService.save(any())).thenReturn(responseDto);


        //when
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/users/save")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(requestDto))
                )
        //then
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().json(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(responseDto)))
                .andDo(print());

    }
}
```

I want to test ExceptionHandler, so I user @BeforeEach annotation for initialize mockMvc.

But, after adding `setup()` method,  JSONException is thrown like these.

```
Unparsable JSON string: 
org.json.JSONException: Unparsable JSON string: 
    at app//org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONParser.parseJSON(JSONParser.java:56)
    at app//org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONCompare.compareJSON(JSONCompare.java:50)
        ,,,
```

There is same exception when I change `ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString` to `jsonpath` which is using for testing response content.

Please let me know why this exception is thrown, thanks.

ps) The others

`UsersController`

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class UsersController extends BaseController {
    private final UsersService usersService;

    @PostMapping("api/users/save")
    public ResponseEntity<?> save (@RequestBody UsersSaveRequestDto requestDto) {
        return sendResponseHttpByJson(usersService.save(requestDto));
    }

    @PostMapping("api/users/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login (@RequestBody UsersLoginRequestDto requestDto) {
        return sendResponseHttpByJson(usersService.login(requestDto));
    }

    @GetMapping("api/users/checkUserExist/{usersId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> checkUserExist (@PathVariable String usersId) {
        return sendResponseHttpByJson(usersService.findByUsersId(usersId));
    }
}
```

`UsersService`

```
package com.ReRollBag.service;

import com.ReRollBag.auth.JwtTokenProvider;
import com.ReRollBag.domain.dto.UsersLoginRequestDto;
import com.ReRollBag.domain.dto.UsersLoginResponseDto;
import com.ReRollBag.domain.dto.UsersResponseDto;
import com.ReRollBag.domain.dto.UsersSaveRequestDto;
import com.ReRollBag.domain.entity.Users;
import com.ReRollBag.exceptions.usersExceptions.UsersIdAlreadyExistException;
import com.ReRollBag.repository.UsersRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Log4j2
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class UsersService {
    private final UsersRepository usersRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Transactional
    public UsersResponseDto save(UsersSaveRequestDto requestDto) {
        Users users = requestDto.toEntity();
        String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(users.getPassword());
        users.setPassword(encryptedPassword);
        usersRepository.save(users);
        return new UsersResponseDto(users);
    }

    public UsersResponseDto findByUsersId (String usersId) {
        Users users = usersRepository.findByUsersId(usersId);
        if (users == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Users is not Exists");
        return UsersResponseDto.builder()
                .users(users)
                .build();
    }

    public Boolean checkUserExist (String usersId) throws UsersIdAlreadyExistException {
        if (usersRepository.existsByUsersId(usersId)) throw new UsersIdAlreadyExistException();
        return true;
    }
    public UsersLoginResponseDto login (UsersLoginRequestDto requestDto) {
        String targetUsersId = requestDto.getUsersId();
        Users targetUsers = usersRepository.findByUsersId(targetUsersId);

        if (targetUsers == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Users Id is wrong");

        if (!passwordEncoder.matches(requestDto.getPassword(), targetUsers.getPassword())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password is wrong");
        }

        if (jwtTokenProvider == null) log.error("jwtTokenProvider is NULL!");
        String accessToken = jwtTokenProvider.createAccessToken(requestDto.getUsersId());
        String refreshToken = jwtTokenProvider.createRefreshToken(requestDto.getUsersId());

        return UsersLoginResponseDto.builder()
                .accessToken(accessToken)
                .refreshToken(refreshToken)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Unable to testing http response's content's json parsing test because of JsonException.
I think there is something wrong with initialize mockMvc.
Please let me know why this Exception is raised.

Answer (score 0):

There is something mistakes with my code. I can catch this error with integration test.

`UsersController.checkUserExist` method calls `UsersService.findByUsersId`, not `UsersService.checkUserExist`.

Also, I don't need to use initialize mockMvc for testing ExceptionHandler.

This is My final code. Please make sense that there is some characters with  Korean.

```
@WebMvcTest(UsersController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class UsersControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private UsersController usersController;

    @MockBean
    private UsersService usersService;

    @MockBean
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @MockBean
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Test
    @DisplayName("[Controller] 회원 가입")
    void Controller_회원가입_테스트() throws Exception {
        //given
        Users users = Users.builder()
                .usersId("test@gmail.com")
                .nickname("testNickname")
                .password("testPassword")
                .build();

        UsersResponseDto responseDto = UsersResponseDto.builder()
                .users(users)
                .build();

        UsersSaveRequestDto requestDto = new UsersSaveRequestDto(
                "test@gmail.com",
                "testNickname",
                "testPassword"
        );

        //mocking
        when(usersService.save(any())).thenReturn(responseDto);


        //when
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/users/save")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(requestDto))
                )
        //then
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().json(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(responseDto)))
                .andDo(print());

    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("[Controller] 로그인 및 토큰 발급")
    void Controller_로그인_토큰발급_테스트() throws Exception {
        //given
        UsersLoginRequestDto requestDto = new UsersLoginRequestDto("test@gmail.com", "testPassword");
        UsersLoginResponseDto responseDto = UsersLoginResponseDto.builder()
                .accessToken("testAccessToken")
                .refreshToken("testRefreshToken")
                .build();
        //mocking
        when(usersService.login(any())).thenReturn(responseDto);
        //when
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/users/login")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(requestDto))
                )
        //then
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().json(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(responseDto)))
                .andDo(print());
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("[Controller] 아이디 중복 검사 성공 case")
    void Controller_아이디_중복검사_성공() throws UsersIdAlreadyExistException {
        //given
        String usersId = "test@gmail.com";
        //mocking
        when(usersService.checkUserExist(usersId)).thenReturn(true);
        //when
        try {
            mockMvc.perform(get("/api/users/checkUserExist/"+usersId))
        //then
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andReturn();
        } catch (UsersIdAlreadyExistException e) {
            throw new UsersIdAlreadyExistException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("[Controller] 아이디 중복 검사 실패 case")
    void Controller_아이디_중복검사_실패() throws UsersIdAlreadyExistException {
        //given
        String usersId = "test@gmail.com";
        //mocking
        when(usersService.checkUserExist(usersId)).thenThrow(UsersIdAlreadyExistException.class);
        //when
        try {
            mockMvc.perform(get("/api/users/checkUserExist/" + usersId))
                    .andExpect(status().isAccepted())
                    .andReturn();
        } catch (UsersIdAlreadyExistException e) {
            throw new UsersIdAlreadyExistException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```